# Reference to IQStreamable not found

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, streaminsight

I am new to `StreamInSight` development. I have downloaded few samples and now I am trying to compile them. I am  getting error as **"The type or namespace name 'IQStreamable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"** I have already included below references into my project -

> - Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing
> - System
> - System.Reactive.Core
> - System.Reactive.Interfaces
> - System.Reactive.Linq
> - System.Reactive.PlatformServices
> - System.Reactive.Providers

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Have you added a using directive for the Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Linq namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the version of StreamInsight you downloaded and installed is v2.1. The IQStreamable interface is new in v2.1. Once you have confirmed that you have the correct version of StreamInsight or installed the correct version, you'll need to make sure you have the appropriate namespace and assembly included with your project. IQStreamable is in the Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Linq namespace and the Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.dll. It also would not hurt to make sure that you are running the most recent version of Rx.